# Why when copying from one instance to another instance does a clear delete the collection from both instances?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ViewModel which contains several objects. One is called Pricelist. The Pricelist object contains a collection.

My steps are as follows:

1. Instantiate a new Pricelist instance (newPricelist).
2. Fill the new instance from the VM. newPricelist = ViewModel.Pricelist (also tried injectFrom)
3. Clear collection inside of new instance. newPricelist.collection.Clear();
4. When this happens the collection is cleared from both the ViewModel.Pricelist as well.

How do I prevent this from happening please?

Comment: See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html

Comment: Reference types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same collection. Rather than clearing out that shared collection, you should assign newPricelist to use a new one. Something like

```
newPricelist.collection = new List<collectionType>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate a new instance of the ICollection(T) object that you're referencing in newPricelist.  So, your code should be more like:

```
newPricelist = new Pricelist();
newPricelist.collection = new List<collectionObject>(ViewModel.Pricelist.collection);
```

Note that your new collection will still refer to the same objects that you have in your ViewModel.Pricelist collection.